# How to set include_type_name in postman to true

Tags: node.js, firebase, elasticsearch, postman

I am creating a mapping index in postman and am getting the error below.
I am trying to create an index that would communicate with my elastic search firebase server using a function I have created index.js. What could be the problem?

Here is my code

```
"mappings":{
        "properties":{
                "city":{
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "contact_email":{
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "country":{
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "description":{
                "type": "text"
                },
                "image":{
                "type": "text"
                },
                "post_id":{
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "state_province":{
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "title":{
                    "type": "text"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the code to index.js function

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const request = require('request-promise')

exports.indexPostsToElastic = functions.database.ref('/posts/{post_id}')
        .onWrite((change,context) =>{
        let postData = change.after.val();
        let post_id = context.params.post_id;

        console.log('Indexing post',postData);

        let elasticSearchConfig = functions.config().elasticsearch;


        let elasticSearchUrl = elasticSearchConfig.url + 'posts/' + post_id;
        let elasticSearchMethod = postData ? 'POST' : 'DELETE';

        let elasticSearchRequest = {
            method:elasticSearchMethod,
                url: elasticSearchUrl,
                auth:{
                    username : elasticSearchConfig.username,
                    password : elasticSearchConfig.password,
                },
                body: postData,
                json : true
              };
              return request(elasticSearchRequest).then(response => {
                  console.log("ElasticSearch response", response);
                  return response;
              });
            });
```

I am getting the following error in firebase

```
StatusCodeError: 400 - {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Rejecting mapping update to [posts] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [_doc, -LcajBAxUn3jrq0EHzYa]"}],
```

Here is a sample of my database in firebase

```
-LcajBAxUn3jrq0EHzYa

city:

contact_email:

country:

description:

image:

post_id:

price:

state_province:

title:
```

Please help me identify where my error could be.

Comment: Can you provide more details here? Whether this is a part of the request body? What is the server code? What exactly are you trying to achieve? Please provide more context so that other people will be able to understand your issue and help you out.

Comment: have you find any solution for it?

Answer (score 2):

`include_type_name` is an elasticsearch flag introduced in last few releases. See background [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/removal-of-types.html#removal-of-types). Its goal is to address the long confusion of elasticsearch `type != tableName`. To include `include_type_name` in your requests, see [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/removal-of-types.html#_typeless_apis_in_7_0).

This is more of a Elasticsearch API problem other than firebase / postman.

Answer (score 1):

You firstly need to check with the elasticSearch version you are using.
If you are using version less than 7.0 then you have to enter your properties tag inside "_doc" field. The "_doc" field is later superseded  in the elasticSearch versions higher than 7.0 . Below is the reformed mapping.

```
"mappings":{
    "_doc" :{
    "properties":{
            "city":{
                "type": "text"
            },
            "contact_email":{
                "type": "text"
            },
            "country":{
                "type": "text"
            },
            "description":{
            "type": "text"
            },
            "image":{
            "type": "text"
            },
            "post_id":{
                "type": "text"
            },
            "state_province":{
                "type": "text"
            },
            "title":{
                "type": "text"
            }
        }
    }
   }
}
```